# Multiple column output in UDAF Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-aggregate

I get some data from my mongodb that looks like this:

```
     +------+-------+
     | view | data  |
     +------+-------+
     |  xx  | ***   |
     |  yy  | ***   |
     |  xx  | ***   |
     +------+-------+
```

It's not really necessary to know what is inside.

I wrote an UserDefinedAggregateFunction like this because I want to group on view.:

```
class Extractor() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction{
  override def inputSchema: StructType = // some stuff

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = 
      StructType(
        List(
          StructField("0",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("1",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("2",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("3",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("4",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("5",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("6",IntegerType,false),
          StructField("7",IntegerType,false)
        )
      )

  override def dataType: DataType = bufferSchema        

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    for (x <- 0 to 7){
      buffer(x) = 0
    }
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = // some stuff

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = // some stuff

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = 
      var l = List.empty[Integer]
      for (x <- 7 to 0 by -1){
          l = buffer.getInt(x) :: l
      }
      l
}
```

My output should be something like this:

```
     +------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     | view | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
     +------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     |  xx  | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
     |  yy  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
     +------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The values are calculated in the update/merge function above but that works and it's not necessary to let you see it.

Then I use it like this:

```
val ex = new Extractor()
val df = dataset.groupBy("view").agg(
      ex(dataset.col("data"))
)
df.show()
```

When I execute df.show() it always give me an IndexOutOfBoundException. I know that it's lazy evaluation that's why I get an error in df.show().

As far as I can see it can execute the first group and end the evaluate function. But after that I get an IndexOutOfBoundException...

Also when I change the dataType and evaluate Function to:

```
override def dataType: DataType =
    ArrayType(IntegerType,false)

override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    var l = ofDim[Integer](8)
    for (x <- 0 to 7){
      l(x) = buffer.getInt(x)
    }
    l
```

The output would look like this:

```
     +------+------------------------------+
     | view | Extractor                    |
     +------+------------------------------+
     |  xx  | [0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0]     |
     |  yy  | [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0]     |
     +------+------------------------------+
```

And the schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- view: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Extractor: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

And I wasn't able to convert this in the form I want.

Because the 2nd approach works I think I mess in the first approach something with the DataType but I don't get how I can fix it...

Many introduction so to my question:

How can I get the output I want?
I don't really care which of the both approach( first with multiple output columns or an array which can conver to the form I want) as long as it's efficient.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the aggregated output to be a list :

```
 override def dataType: DataType = bufferSchema
```

Because `bufferSchema` is a List, this is what you get in the end. You can alter later your schema and transform each column from your list into a new column.

For your error, the difference between :

```
override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = 
  var l = List.empty[Integer]
  for (x <- 7 to 0 by -1){
      l = buffer.getInt(x) :: l
  }
  l
```

and

```
override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = 
  var l = ofDim[Integer](8)
  for (x <- 0 to 7){
    l = buffer.getInt(x) :: l
  }
  l
```

is that in the second one, you define a predefined number of columns. Therefore, you are certain you can iterate from 0 to 7 without problem.

It's not the case for your first example, therefore, I suspect that you may have a misformatted data that makes your buffer to be wrongly initialized in `initialize` or `merge`. I'll suggesst you add a try/catch to validate the size after each step that transform the length of your buffer (at least `initialize` but could be `update` or `merge` too).

To add column for each element from your list, you can either use `withColumn` or do it through a map.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. It's always 0 (I added the initialize method so you can see that I'm sure that's always 8)   and about: "You can alter later your schema and transform each column from your list into a new column." when I know how I would do it

Comment: What about the merge function. Are you checking that the row is not null ?

Comment: it's impossible that they are null. and if they are null then the second approach wouldn't work.